# Segfault at end of program

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I wrote this program as a side project from one of my professors. It reads in a Sudoku puzzle from a 9x9 block in a given text file, and then solves it visibly using a recursive, backtracking linked list. This is done well, but I always get a segfault at the end of execution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int ctoi(char c);
void printBoard();
int board[9][9];

class Node
{
    public:
    int x_, y_;
    int value;
    Node* next_;
    bool checkAllowed();
    bool processNextNode();
    bool requiredValue;
};

bool Node::checkAllowed()
{

    int checkVal = value;
    //Check vertically
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if(i != y_)
        {
            int compareVal = board[x_][i];
            if(board[x_][i] == value)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    //Check horizontally
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if(i != x_)
        {
            if(board[i][y_] == value)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    //Check 3x3 block
    int offsetX = x_ - x_ % 3;
    int offsetY = y_ - y_ % 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        int x, y;
        x = offsetX + i % 3;
        y = offsetY + i / 3;
        if (x != x_ && y != y_)
        {
            if(board[x][y] == value)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool Node::processNextNode()
{
    if(requiredValue)
    {
        if(next_ == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return next_ -> processNextNode();
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        value = i;
        if(checkAllowed())
        {
            board[x_][y_] = value;
            printBoard();
            if(next_ == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if(next_ -> processNextNode())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    char* fileName;
    ifstream fin;
    Node* head;
    Node* next = new Node();
    head = next;

    cout << "Enter file name : ";
    cin >> fileName;

    fin.open(fileName);

    if(fin == 0)
    {
        cout << "File does not exist" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
        char* line;
        fin >> line;
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            board[j][i] = ctoi(line[j]);
            if(board[j][i] == 0)
            {
                next -> requiredValue = false;
            }
            else
            {
                next -> requiredValue = true;
            }
            next -> x_ = j;
            next -> y_ = i;
            next -> value = board[j][i];
            if(i == 8 && j == 8)
            {
                next -> next_ = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                next -> next_ = new Node;
                next = next -> next_;
            }
        }
    }

    printBoard();

    bool good = head -> processNextNode();

    printBoard();
    if(!good)
    {
        cout << "Puzzle is unsolveable." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int ctoi(char c)
{
    if(c == '.')
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return (int) c - (int) '1' + 1;
}

void printBoard()
{
    system("cls");
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            cout << board[j][i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I am new to c++ pointers and I think this may be the result of improper deletion of some element. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `std::string` rather than an uninitialised `char*` to hold strings.

Comment: But there don't seem to be any manual `delete`s in your programme (despite the fact there should be as you're using `new` to allocate `Node`s).

Comment: Manual deletion of the fileName string did the trick. I came from Java to c++ a few months ago and I'm still figuring it out.

Comment: I'm surprised it waits for exit to segfault.  Because `fileName` is uninitialised, `cin >> fileName` is overwriting random bytes in memory.  As Mike has suggested, replace `char* fileName` with `std::string fileName`.

Answer (score 2):

This line of code:

```
cin >> fileName;
```

means "Read a string from standard input and put the content of that string at the location pointed to by `fileName`."  Unfortunately, `fileName` is an uninitialised pointer, so it's overwriting random bytes in memory.

Since it waits until process exit to segfault, it seems likely that what is being overwritten is part of the process cleanup handlers.

The easiest way to fix this is to instead write:

```
#include <string>
...
std::string fileName;
...
cin >> fileName;
fin.open(fileName);
```